# Template destreoyed, Regions lost after Flush Caches

Tags: theming, caching

I did a Flush all caches - and all my Template is destroyed and my own made Regions disappeared, their content showed up as disabled, due to "invalid region"....

It's a production site, it was working well for half a year.....
What's up? What to do now?

Comment: Is it reverting to the regions of the active theme at the time of the cache clear (probably the admin theme)? Then if you clear the cache again from the home page (or some other page showing the main theme) it fixes it?
 Or not? Or has your main theme unexpectedly become disabled?

Comment: My Template is Zen sub-template, it shows as active; I was not doing anything about template lately and everything was fine....I was updating Menu in Mysql, that's the only reason I did flush...

Comment: May be it's because it was on Cloudflare  cache as well? But I disabled Cloudflare  now and it didn't improved..

Comment: Restore from backup, hacking the database is dangerous.

Comment: It sounds like the custom subtheme isn't being recognised. Your regions will re-appear when it is. I'd make a local copy of the site and have a look at the PHP error logs etc. to try and diagnose the problem